# Add a column to a CSV that's a sum of the two previous columns

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I am trying to manipulate a big data set, but I will use a simple example here. I am trying to add two columns to form a third column.

Input CSV

```
1,11  
2,12
3,13
4,14
5,15
```

Desired Output CSV

```
1,11,12
2,12,14
3,13,16
4,14,18
5,15,20
```

I have been trying the below line and I am getting the wrong output.

```
awk -F, '{$3=$1+$2;} {print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, filename.csv
```

Comment: What output are you getting, exactly?

Comment: @steeldriver this is the output, 
    ,121
    ,142
    ,163
    ,184
    ,205

Comment: Your code example works here

Comment: Is this a Windows file, perhaps?

Comment: @terdon i have used multiple csv file types and my results always come out jumbled together. I am just using small data sets but need this to work at scale. It works with just using a two column output but once I try to add the third I run into problems.

Comment: The thing is that what you show here should work. If it isn't working, then there's something strange in your file. So, please [edit] your question and paste an actual example from the file into it, using the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look like code. Also paste the exact output you get when you run it. The jumbling you describe is hard to understand if you don't actually show it, but certainly sounds like you have `\r` characters in there as you would if the file had ever been edited on macOS or Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Either of these:

```
awk -F, '{print $1","$2","$1+$2}' filename.csv
awk -F, '{$0=$1","$2","$1+$2}1' filename.csv
```

And for what it's worth, your example in the question worked fine for me.  Locally and via awk.js.org tool.

```
$ awk -F, '{$3=$1+$2;} {print $1,$2,$3}' OFS=, filename.csv
1,11,12
2,12,14
3,13,16
4,14,18
5,15,20
$
```

[image: works fine using online awk tool]

Comment: whoa, awk REPL! nice

Comment: @steve I am working from both the unix and linux cmd line, and my results keep getting jumbled like so, 
    ,110
    ,131
    ,152
    ,173
    ,194
    ,215
    ,236
    ,257
    9,18,27

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F ',' '{$3=$1+$2;} {print $1","$2","$3}' filename.csv
```